# Convert eml to markdown with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, eml

I have downloaded eml files from gmail and wanted to convert the mail content to markdown.
The code I have used is this:

```
import os
import email
from markdownify import markdownify as md
from email import message_from_file
from email import policy
from email.parser import BytesParser
import glob

    files = glob.glob("file_gmail.eml") # returns list of files
with open(files[0], "rb") as fp:
    msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
    asunto = msg['subject']
    msgmkd = md(msg.get_body(preferencelist=("html")).get_content())
    file = open(asunto + '.md', 'w')
    file.write(msgmkd)
    file.close()
```

The downside is that it leaves me the CSS and some other things and I am not able to remove it. The code that leaves at the beginning of the text is this:

```
html [if !mso]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif] .ExternalClass { width: 100%; background: inherit; background-color: inherit; } .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass ul, .ExternalClass ol { Margin: 0; } .undoreset div p, .undoreset p { margin-bottom: 20px; } div[class^="aolmail\_divbody"] { overflow: auto; } [owa] #ac-footer { padding: 20px 0px !important; background: inherit; background-color: inherit; }  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /*----------------
...
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is `md`? Presumably you're using a Markdown library? Which one?

Comment: The library is: from markdownify import markdownify as md

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style (and possibly other tags) in advance, with beautifulsoup

```
asunto = msg['subject']
html = msg.get_body(preferencelist=("html")).get_content()

dom = BS(html, features="html.parser")
elements = dom.select('style,script')
for element in elements: _ = element.extract()

msgmkd = md(str(dom))
```